# How to triple des C# method according to swift method

Tags: c#, swift, swift3, swift4

How to change C# encryption method to the same as swift? I tried below code, but it's converting the string different. I want according to same as swift due to decryption method. I am using 3des. My C# method encrypt/decrypt is working fine.
I want same as C# in Swift.

C#

```
public static string Encrypt(string PlainText)
{
    try
    {
        if (PlainText.Length > 0)
        {
            string key = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD";
            byte[] PlainTextArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
            byte[] keyArray = MD5.CreateMd5ByteArray(key);

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TripleDes.Key = keyArray;
            TripleDes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TripleDes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = TripleDes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] CipherString = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(PlainTextArray, 0, PlainTextArray.Length);
            TripleDes.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherString, 0, CipherString.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

SWIFT

```
 func tripleDesEncrypt(PlainString: String) -> String{

   let keyData = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD"

    let PlainStringvar       = PlainString

    guard let data = PlainStringvar.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return ""           
    }
    let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.count) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                              algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                              nil,
                              data.bytes, data.count,
                              cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

       var base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)


        return base64cryptString//// encodeString(str: base64cryptString)

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: If you need to derive an encryption key from a password do not use MD5 or just a cryptographic hash function, that is not secure. Use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2, Rfc2898DeriveBytes, Argon2 or similar functions with a CPU utilization of about 100ms. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force. – zaph 1 min ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in C# appears to be this line:

```
byte[] keyArray = MD5.CreateMd5ByteArray(key);
```

Assuming that function (which is not part of the .NET BCL, so I assume it's something custom that you wrote) creates an MD5 hash of your 3DES key, that's the only difference between your C# and Swift versions.

In Swift, you encrypt the value using a key which is the UTF-8 encoded value of `"FIFE..."`.

In C#, you encrypt the value using a key which is the **MD5 hash of** the UTF-8 encoded value if `"FIFE..."`.

If you replace that line with the following one:

```
var keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
```

then both functions return the same ciphertext for the same plaintext values.